# Given only the Mean, Q1, Q2, and Q3, is there a way to predict the value that would fall at the 60th percentile?

Tags: regression

It's been a while since I've had to mess around with statistics like this. I only have the mean, 25th percentile, median, and 75th percentile. I am attempting to predict with reasonable accuracy what value would fall at the 60th percentile. Is this possible with the data I have available? Or would I need more?

An example of the data would be something like this:

Mean - 456,000 ;
25th Percentile - 328,000 ;
Median - 384,000 ;
75th Percentile - 516,000.

Comment: Do you have literally no other information? No lower bound on the numbers? (like necessarily being non-negative, say?) No sample size?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information/assumptions, the quartiles alone only restrict the 60th percentile to be between (or equal to) the quartiles either side of it (in this case the 50th and 75th percentiles).

The mean potentially adds information but typically won't provide enough additional information to constrain the value further (sometimes it might, particularly if it can be combined with still other information, but typically there will be possible arrangements of data values that still allows the 60th percentile to reach both quartile limits).

In the case of your specific example, the mean doesn't appear constrain the possible value of the 60th percentile beyond it being in the interval $[384000, 516000]$. Without more information (perhaps including the things I specifically asked about in comments), it looks like both those endpoints are possible.

For example, here's a case (of invented data) where the 60th percentile is the same as the 75th percentile (values are in thousands):

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  328.0   328.0   384.0   465.0   516.0   671.8 
quantile(x,.6)
60% 
516
```

Comment: Most people forced to guess would not say $516000$ even if it is possible

Comment: Sure, that's true, but they're relying on *additional* information (or perhaps 'information') outside the actual values. In trying to respond to "Is this possible ***with the data I have available***?" the answer is "not beyond the actual quartiles either side, without additional information/assumptions" (e.g people will often tend to assume things like continuous, smooth, unimodal, ...); naturally when you bring in external assumptions, things change. However, what most people might suppose may well be out of place here, we can't tell when there's no actual information beyond those 4 numbers.

Comment: So you need some reasonable assumptions, and these should be stated.  But that is not uncommon in statistical estimation and your `quantile` function in fact does that when interpolating

Comment: Sure, no disagreement there. Reasonable assumptions would normally be explored with the people in a position to make them (people with relevant domain knowledge). I don't think that changes my answer in any way; I've provided the necessary caveats about assumptions.